# Installed Bitcoind on my Ubuntu server, but where does the blockchain get downloaded?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12 and just installed bitcoind. How do i find out where its installed and where is it downloading the entire blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory), it is shored here

```
Linux
By default Bitcoin will put its data here:
~/.bitcoin/
```

Answer (score -3):

A bit more specific than a previous answer, the default path for blocks in `~/.bitcoin/blocks`